# Japanese keyboard in wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7, keyboard

I've implemented textbox.Keydown event in my wp7 project to lose focus and make soft keyboard hide on key press.It works fine with US soft keyboard.But when i change the system language and key board to Japanese the key down  event is not called when i press the keys and are able to insert text using keyboard.
How to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try to subscribe to the [`TextChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.textchanged%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) event instead.

Comment: Thanks.On key press TextChanged event is raised but it inserts that letter  to the textbox.I dont want the letter to be inserted...any ideas on this?

Comment: @user1659708 Well, if you don't want text to be inserted, your approach is flawed even without the Japanese keyboard, since the user can still paste text. Maybe you can save the text you want to display inside a string property, and restore it when the `TextChanged` event is triggered.

Comment: Hey KooKiz,your suggestion did work out.i did restore the string when key events are raised.Thanks a lot